# File not found Python

Tags: python

I have tried to get my program to open but it keeps saying `FileNotFound`

```
def main():
   with open("number.txt") as f:
       nums=[int(x) for x in f.read().split()]
   print(nums)
   for nums in nums:
       total += int(nums)
   print(total) 
   print(len(nums))
   return total / len(nums)
main()
```

Comment: Does `number.txt` exist? Did you try to give the full path to the file?

Comment: Is "number.txt" in the same directory where you run the script?

Comment: BTW Once you fixed that problem you will get the next one related to the double use of `nums`.

Comment: I have the file number.txt in the same folder as python, isn't what's required for python to read the file?

Comment: It should be in the same folder as your code.

Comment: It should be in the **current working directory**, which in many case is the same as directory of the code you are running, but not always.

Comment: It is in the same folder as python and the script itself

Answer (score 0):

Python will look for "number.txt" in your current directory which by default is the same folder that your code started running in. You can get the current directory by using `os.getcwd()` and if that for some reason is not what you expect, you can also get the directory to the folder that your code is running in by doing `current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`.

The following code should always work, if you want your "number.txt" to be in the same folder as your code.

```
import os.path

def main():
    current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filepath = os.path.join(current_directory, "number.txt")

    # Optionally use this to create the file if it does not exist
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        open(filepath, 'w').close()

    with open( filepath ) as f:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `number.txt` in your working directory? If not you'd have to specify the path to that file so python knows where to look